# Entity Framework - configure optional:required with different foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to setup a optional:required relationship between two entities, `Fund` and `RedemptionFee`.  A fund may or may not have a redemption fee, but a redemption fee requires a fund.  The model is basically this (non-relevant properties omitted)

```
public class Fund
{
    public int FundId {get; set;}
    public string FundCode {get; set;}

    public virtual RedemptionFee RedemptionFee {get; set;}
}

public class RedemptionFee
{
    public string FundCode {get; set;}
    public virtual Fund Fund {get; set;}
}
```

What I think is the problem is the fact that on the `Fund` object, `FundId` is my primary key, and needs to stay this way because there are about 6 or 7 other entities that `Fund` is related to via the `FundId`.  On `RedemptionFee`, `FundCode` is the primary key.  `FundCode` is also part of the `Fund` object, but is not the primary key.

When I try to configure the relationship like this (in an `EntityTypeConfiguration` object for Fund)

```
HasOptional(f=>f.RedemptionFee).WithRequired(f=>f.Fund);
```

The generated SQL is trying to join the Fund table to the `RedemptionFee` table with each of their primary keys, which obviously isn't going to work.  I need to specify that the generated SQL join the two tables via the `FundCode`.

Is there a way to do this?  It's pretty basic SQL but it seems to be impossible in EF unless I"m missing something.  EF seems to require the foreign key on the dependent be the same as the primary key on the primary when defining a relationship, and I'd like to basically pick an arbitrary column to use to define that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In an one to one relationship there is a principal and a dependent entity. In the dependent entity is where you declare the FK property, which also is PK of that entity, so it will match with the PK of your principal. 
What I suggest to do to solve your problem is use `FundCode` as PK in your Fund entity:

```
public class Fund
{
    [Key]
    public string FundCode {get; set;}

    public virtual RedemptionFee RedemptionFee {get; set;}
}

public class RedemptionFee
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Fund")]
    public string FundCode {get; set;}
    public virtual Fund Fund {get; set;}
}
```

Now, you said you can't change your model, well, you could create then two relationships to achieve the model you need:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Fund>().HasOptional(f=>f.RedemptionFee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f=>f.FundCode);
modelBuilder.Entity<RedemptionFee>().HasRequired(f=>f.RedemptionFee).WithMany();
```

But of course with these configurations your entities are not going to be related directly.